# Removing a column from some files when merging multiple CSV files

Tags: r, csv, rbind

I have several CSV files that I am merging to one data frame using a for loop and `rbind`. My issue is, however, that some of these CSV files contain a column that is causing problems during `rbind` when merging the files together. The column name is `fbclid` and I attach the code I am using to achieve this below:

```
library(dplyr)

OnExpDir = dir()
OnExpList=grep("PARTICIPANT", OnExpDir, value = T)
#Creating a participant column, as a unique identifier for each participant
OnExpData <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x, y) transform(read.csv(x), pp = paste0('pp', y)), paste0(getwd(), "/", OnExpList), seq_along(OnExpList)))
```

This yields the following error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Alternatively, I have a `for` loop that accomplishes the task, but I would need a solution to append a participant ID for every .csv file loaded in.

```
OnExpDir = dir()
OnExpList=grep("PARTICIPANT", OnExpDir, value = T)

#Binding data to one table
OnExpData=NULL
for(myfile in OnExpList)
{
  fullExpFileName = paste(getwd(), "/", myfile, sep = "")
  TMPData = read.csv(fullExpFileName, header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)
  if("fbclid" %in% colnames(TMPData)){
    TMPData$fbclid=NULL
  }
  OnExpData = rbind(OnExpData, TMPData)
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using the bind_rows function from the dplyr package.  That should handle the difference with the number of columns without creating an error.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dave2e, that has solved it.